# Need help pushing Zapier Webhook url to Go High Level

Tags: zapier

My problem is I don't know steps to create webhook.

What are specific steps to create a Zapier webhook (url) for me to push lead data from private crm to go high level?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a free account on Zapier, webhooks aren't supported. If you're looking for an alternatives that doesn't limit your abilities to receive webhooks for free, I created this open source app: https://github.com/activepieces/activepieces

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).